# Determine if a value the user inputs already exists for a login page in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project and includes the ability for the user to create an account on the site.  I've been able to set up the database and connect the page to the database and when a user creates an account, the information is added to a table in the database called Users; however, if a duplicate email address is entered I don't want the information to be added to the database and to display to the user to enter another email address. I have been able to prevent duplicate entries by using a UNIQUE INDEX table but I haven't been able to figure out how to first check for an existing email and display an error if one already exists.

register.php (form)

```
<?php

if(!isset($fName) && !isset($lName) && !isset($zip) && !isset($email) && 
    !isset($password)) {
    $fName = '';
    $lName = '';
    $zip = '';
    $email = '';
    $password = '';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Register</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/CentralPerk/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="formstyles.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="aside">
         <h1>Register For An Account</h1>
    </div>

    <form action="index.php" method="post" id="registration_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register">

        <label>Personal Information</label>
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First Name" required
                value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fName); ?>" />
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" required 
                value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($lName); ?>" />
        <br>
        <br>

        <input name="zip" id="zipcode" type="text" placeholder="Zipcode" required
            pattern="^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$" 
            value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($zip); ?>" />
        <br>
        <br>

        <label>Account Information</label>
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Email Address" required
                value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>" />
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="password" required
                value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($password); ?>" />
        <br>
        <br>

    </form>

    <button type="submit" form="registration_form" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

index.php (register form connects to index.php when the user submits the form)

```
<?php
require('../model/database.php');
require('../model/account_db.php');

//form value is 'action'
$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');

if($action == 'register') {
    $fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fName');
    $lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lName');
    $zip = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'zip', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

//this is where I am trying to determine if the email entered already exists,
//if it does not, it executes the add_user method in the account_db.php file

$checkUserEmail = $db -> query("SELECT UserEmail FROM Users 
                                WHERE `UserEmail` = $email");

if ($checkUserEmail === TRUE) {
    $message = "User already exists";
    include('../model/test.php');
}
else {
    add_user($fName, $lName, $zip, $email);
    header('../CentralPerk/index.php');
}

}
?>
```

account_db.php (adds user to database)

```
<?php

function add_user($fName, $lName, $zip, $email) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'INSERT INTO Users
                (UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserZipcode, UserEmail) 
              VALUES 
                (:fName, :lName, :zip, :email)';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':fName', $fName);
    $statement->bindValue(':lName', $lName);
    $statement->bindValue(':zip', $zip);
    $statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}

?>
```

accounts.sql

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS accounts;
CREATE DATABASE accounts;
USE accounts;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON *
TO mgs_user@localhost
IDENTIFIED BY 'pa55word';

CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserID              BIGINT              NOT NULL                AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserFirstName       VARCHAR(60)         NOT NULL,
    UserLastName        VARCHAR(60)         NOT NULL,
    UserZipcode         INT                 NOT NULL,
    UserEmail           VARCHAR(60)         NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(UserID)

);

 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_idx ON Users (
    UserEmail
);
```

Comment: Why are using a parameterized query for `function add_user()`, but not for `$checkUserEmail` query? It would help with your issue of an unquoted string value, `...WHERE \`UserEmail\` = $email` should be `...WHERE \`UserEmail\` = '$email'`, but would be better as a `...WHERE \`UserEmail\` = :email`

Comment: @Sean That worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if ($checkUserEmail === TRUE) {
```

Use

```
if($checkUserEmail->num_rows >= 1)
```